# Subtracting Datetimes

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, datediff

I'm trying to find the most simple way to subtract to DATETIMEs from each other to produce a difference in the format of YY:MM.

Concatenating DATEDIFF of the two periods by year and month clearly just combines the same time differences together so a time period that is 2 years apart shows 2yrs,24months, when I am hoping to get it to show 2yrs,0months.

```
DATEDIFF(y,startdate,GETDATE())
```

Any tips? Thanks! Using SQL Server.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by constructing it with `CONCAT()` using the `DATEDIFF()` results by the month:

```
Select  Concat
        (
            Right('00' + Convert(Varchar, DateDiff(Month, StartDate, GetDate()) / 12), 2), 
            ':', 
            Right('00' + Convert(Varchar, DateDiff(Month, StartDate, GetDate()) % 12), 2)
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select Concat(DateDiff(YY,StartDate,GetDate()),' Yrs,')+Concat((DateDiff(MM,StartDate,GetDate()))  % 12,' months')
```

Returns
2 Yrs,2 months

-- Assuming StartDate is 2014-04-29